# Failed to run php spark serve, can anyone solve the problem?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The error I receive when starting spark is

```
Constant FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated
```

can anyone solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a PHP version that is too new for the codeigniter version you installed.

If you're using PHP 8.1 you need at least codeigniter 4.1.7

Solutions:

- Option1: Downgrade PHP
- Option2: Upgrade Codeigniter

Reference: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelogs/v4.1.7.html